# Sliding ScatterViewItems from table to close

Tags: touch, multi-touch, pixelsense

currently I'm developing a project for the Pixelsense/Surface 2.0/Sur40. I'm wondering if it is possible to slide `ScatterViewItems` from the table. For me it is the most intuitive way to close an item. By default `ScatterViewItems` bounce from the edges of the screen.
At the moment I'm closing items with two buttons to secure that the item isn't accidentally closed.

[image: The ScatterViewItem that should be closed by sliding]

If someone has an idea how it is or can be done, please let me know.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Could you check the SVI's Center property? or combine the center property with some trigonometry to find the corners.  Then during a Manipulation event check if the Center or corners have fallen off the edge of the ScatterView.

I believe you're not allowed to push more than 85% of the visible area of the SVI off the ScatterView.  Meaning you can't push it all the way off the table, there'll always be a little corner left for you to grab it again.  From a UI standpoint though, you'd have to instruct people to throw things off, and I've found Surfaces to be pretty jumpy and easy to move things in ways you don't want.  I'd personally stick with a button unless your audience is comfortable figuring things out on the fly.

Comment: It is a study, where I want to see if the user use such gestures. But if you say there is always 15% visible it could be confusing if the process is closing.

Comment: I'm having trouble finding the post that I got the 85% number from, but  the answer here from MS is relevant: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/surfaceappdevelopment/thread/e9d29187-60c9-4b87-8266-503fec65b473  It's certainly possible to throw an SVI way off or programmatically tell it to disappear, but it's not built in to the ScatterView/Item relationship.